# BigQuery combining data sets using dates and date ranges

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, date-range

Is there a way to combine 2 tables by serial number and using a date range from one table and dates from the other?

I have 2 tables: table.events contains event data for a tracker, and table.dates contains the operational date of a tracker. A tracker can be in operation multiple times and as such, has a UID every time it is turned on. E.g. Tracker A can have the UID A1, A2, A3 etc.

How can I combine table.events with data such as

```
Date,Serial,Quality,
12/01/2019,A,1,
12/01/2019,B,2,
13/01/2019,C,3,
14/01/2019,A,4,
15/01/2019,A,5,
16/01/2019,B,6,
17/01/2019,B,7,
17/01/2019,C,8,
17/01/2019,B,9
```

with table.dates

```
Start_Date,End_Date,Serial_id,
15/01/2019,18/01/2019,A1,
08/01/2019,14/01/2019,A2,
10/02/2019,18/01/2019,B1,
13/01/2019,16/01/2019,C1,
17/02/2019,18/01/2019,C2
```

To give me an end result such as

```
Date,Serial,Serial_id,Quality,Start Date,End Date
12/01/2019,A,A1,1,15/01/2019,18/01/2019
12/01/2019,B,B1,2,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
13/01/2019,C,C1,3,13/01/2019,16/01/2019
14/01/2019,A,A1,4,15/01/2019,18/01/2019
15/01/2019,A,A2,5,08/01/2019,14/01/2019
16/01/2019,B,B1,6,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
17/01/2019,B,B1,7,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
17/01/2019,C,C2,8,17/02/2019,18/01/2019
17/01/2019,B,B1,9,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

## Edit:

One date will contain more than one serial number, so I want to also join by serial number.

E.g.

I have trackers D1 and E1 which both were tracking on 23/01/2019. I have seperate entries in table.events for D and E so I will need to match by date range and by a substring of serial id.

Comment: I have tried everything but I still can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `join`?

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     b
     on b.serial like concat(a.serial, '%') and
        a.date >= b.start_date and a.date <= b.end_date;
```

Comment: Yes but that would not give me the result I require. I also want to match the serial numbers as multiple serial numbers can exist in a date range.