# BigQuery joing 2 tables based on 2 values

Tags: sql, datetime, join, google-bigquery

Asking again as I had no luck before

Is there a way to combine 2 tables by serial number and using a date range from one table and dates from the other?

I have 2 tables: table.events contains event data for a tracker, and table.dates contains the operational date of a tracker. A tracker can be in operation multiple times and as such, has a UID every time it is turned on. E.g. Tracker A can have the UID A1, A2, A3 etc.

How can I combine table.events with data such as

```
Date,Serial,Quality,
12/01/2019,A,1,
12/01/2019,B,2,
13/01/2019,C,3,
14/01/2019,A,4,
15/01/2019,A,5,
16/01/2019,B,6,
17/01/2019,B,7,
17/01/2019,C,8,
17/01/2019,B,9
```

with table.dates

```
Start_Date,End_Date,Serial_id,
15/01/2019,18/01/2019,A1,
08/01/2019,14/01/2019,A2,
10/02/2019,18/01/2019,B1,
13/01/2019,16/01/2019,C1,
17/02/2019,18/01/2019,C2
```

To give me an end result such as

```
Date,Serial,Serial_id,Quality,Start Date,End Date
12/01/2019,A,A1,1,15/01/2019,18/01/2019
12/01/2019,B,B1,2,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
13/01/2019,C,C1,3,13/01/2019,16/01/2019
14/01/2019,A,A1,4,15/01/2019,18/01/2019
15/01/2019,A,A2,5,08/01/2019,14/01/2019
16/01/2019,B,B1,6,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
17/01/2019,B,B1,7,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
17/01/2019,C,C2,8,17/02/2019,18/01/2019
17/01/2019,B,B1,9,10/02/2019,18/01/2019
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

ALSO:

One date will contain more than one serial number, so I want to also join by serial number.

E.g.

I have trackers D1 and E1 which both were tracking on 23/01/2019. I have seperate entries in table.events for D and E so I will need to match by date range and by a substring of serial id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BigQuery combining data sets using dates and date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764522/bigquery-combining-data-sets-using-dates-and-date-ranges)

Comment: If your question did not get enough attention, edit the question to make it more clear as well as concise to help garner an acceptable answer, but do not copy and paste the same question.

Answer (score 1):

you can merge all the data using

```
select
     Date,
     Serial,
     Serial_id,
     Quality,
     Start Date,
     End Date
from
     events,
     dates;
```

however, if you wanna join the tables on a specific value you need a value, in best case an id, that are a value of each table.

I am not able to conclude what data could be used to connect the event and the operation. A possible solution would be to implement the serial id in the event table. then you could find this value in both tables and use the code:

```
select
    event.Date,
    event.Serial,
    event.quality,
    event.serial_id
    date.start date
    date.end date
from
    event
full outer join
    date
on
    date.serial_id=event.serial_id;
```

If you have any further questions do not hesitate to get back to me.

Best regards,

Jens

Answer (score 0):

How are you joining by dates? By looking at your sample result, it does not look like event.Date falls into the range of dates.Start_date and dates.End_date

If you just want to join by the serial ID, you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM events e 
inner join dates d 
on e.Serial = substring(d.Serial_id, 1, 1)
```

If you do want to add date range as a constrain, you can append

```
and e.Date <= d.End_date and e.Date >= d.Start_date
```